# Create ftp user next to DirectAdmin users

Tags: ftp, user-accounts

For my server which uses DirectAdmin I would like to create an ftp user which can access every directory in /home/ . I don't need to know how to do this, I know how to jail. The problem I am facing is quite simple I guess.

I am using these two commands to create my user;

```
sudo useradd userftp -p your_password -s /bin/false
sudo passwd userftp
```

After I should be able to login with ftp I guess? The problem is that every time I try to login I receive an 530 login incorrect error. Other accounts created with DirectAdmin are working.

Thanks!

Comment: Which ftp daemon are you using ? Is it configured to read local user accounts or does it use it's own account management backend ?

Comment: proftpd, how can I find that out?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem: I use proFTPd as well, created a user via ssh (used the root account), set the right permissions for the user and the user just doesn't show up in /etc/proftpd.passwd. Also not able to login via ssh (but thats not an issue at this moment)

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me is the following:
After you created your user you have to manually add the user with password into the proftpd.passwd file.

1. Generate a **crypt-md5** password via for example https://www.mkpasswd.net/
2. Retreive the userid and group id (f.e. in /etc/passwd)
3. `nano /etc/proftpd.passwd`
4. Enter the line into proftpd.passwd, should be something like this:

   `myuser:$1$6xj8db37dskds8c3b9:123:124:custom:/home:/bin/bash`

Your user can login via this password, the one that you have set via the `passwd` command is not the one that is used...